# Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol, xcode4.6.3

I have some problem with my project. Can someone who's good in `xcode` help me up with that linker error on skype or teamviewer? I didn't made that code but it was working earlier but now it shows some linker error

> Command
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Is that the one and only error?

Comment: i fixed it somehow but i hav another error in that code now....can u teamview or skype me?

Comment: not me. sorry. could you post the error?

Comment: i removed the error but now the segments lost the colour they had earlier.....it was working earlier though....and moreover the code is not done my me as i dont hav any knowledge of segments

Comment: Please post some code with the "segments" that you talk about.

Comment: sorry ur comment was not visible for a long time.....i posted my implementation file and there are 4 more files that work as header files to the ViewController implementation and header file. I still haven't posted.Tell me if u need them.

Comment: i removed the code as i think i found an answer myself....thanx for your concern

Comment: Please post your answer below for others to find

Comment: The problem was that i didn't set the <UIScrollViewDelegate> in my header file so the scrolls on my app were never displayed.Sorry for asking a noob question.
And that linker error got fixed when i copied my header files and implementation files in another new xcode project.I think the problem was that i mistakenly deleted the nib file once and then made another one from "New File" option but that basically arosed those disastrous problems for me.

Comment: I will +1 that so others can find it

Comment: HI @PradeepMittal plz let us know how you solve the below error so tat other visitor can also get it... Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Comment: I am also facing the same issue like Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1, What should be the solution for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 >I was using scrollview delegate methods in my project when i didn't set the UIScrollViewDelegate in my header file.

2 >The linker error was generated because I deleted the whole .xib file once but when I added a new .xib file and tried to link it that aroused this error.

To fix this error I had to make a new project and copied all my code in that new project.There may be an easier way to do this but this is what I did to fix it.

Comment: When adding files in Xcode you need to do: File -> Add files to "YourProject"...
This will make it so this error doesn't arise.

Answer (score 1):

Ref [Bridging-header.h causes Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177580/bridging-header-h-causes-command-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-tool/32117504#32117504)[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning 'Other Librarian Flags' of all content works