# Bridging-header.h causes Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, typhoon

If i add this line to my `PROJECT-Bridging-Header.h` file

```
#import "Typhoon.h"
```

Xcode 6.1 throws this error
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1`

Typhoon framework is added by CocoaPods exactly like in the tutorial

I tried several thinks, but nothing helped

- Delete XCODE deriver data
- create new Project
- delete and create new bridging-header.h file

Comment: So, we missed this. Did you get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ran across a similar kind of issue, needed to clean up the project Compile Sources listed under Build Phases. Ref to image

This issue creeped due to multiple structural changes done on the project by multiple people via a common source repository.

[image]

Comment: When you say "remove all files that are highlighted in red, @Abhileet, do you mean everything under Compile Sources that has a red background? Or do you mean everything in the red box that you drew? And if it's the latter, to you mean all files, or just the ones that you listed?

Comment: @vbullinger Most likely "everything under Compile Sources that has a red background"